# issues in event response

Tags: javascript, jquery

I can't understand why `Test` keep on firing even though the class `open` has been added to it ? any idea on how to make it in the right way so it will stop on firing when open class is added?

```
<div class="changer">Test</div>
$(".changer:not('open')").on("click",function(){
        $(this).addClass("open");
        alert("passed");
    })
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ng2guchg/

Comment: You should use `.off()` to turn the listener off when you don't need it http://api.jquery.com/off/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because the elements are gotten when the page loads, and the event handler is attached at that moment, changing the class later doesn't remove the event handler.

The solution is to either check for the class inside the event handler

```
$(".changer").on("click", function(){
    if ( ! $(this).hasClass('open') ) {
        $(this).addClass("open");
        alert("passed");
    }
});
```

or to make the event handler fire only once, you could use jQuery `one()` if it fits your needs.

Comment: @user3135757 - my bad, I read that wrong, you shouldn't use delegated handlers for not matching a class, check the class in the event handler

Comment: Thanks now it works ! but when to use delegated handlers and when not?

Comment: Generally, you use delegated handlers when you have dynamically inserted elements, but they can also be useful for dynamically added classes, like in this case, but not when you need to check if the class is not added.

Comment: Also, using `off` as suggested by Simon, can be a good idea to remove the event handler if you don't need, then you really wouldn't even need the classes -> `$(this).off('click')`